# AlarmManager triggers before scheduled time

Tags: java, android, android-notifications, android-alarms, android-broadcastreceiver

I am trying to generate a notification after 10 minutes a particular button has been clicked.To do this I used `AlarmManager` and the `NotificationManager` classes. Below is my code

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();


        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void scheduleAlarm(View V)
    {

        Long time = new GregorianCalendar().getTimeInMillis()+5*60*1000;

        Calendar cur_cal = new GregorianCalendar();
        cur_cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis()+10*60*1000);//set the current time and date for this calendar

        Intent intentAlarm = new Intent(this, AlarmReciever.class);

        // create the object
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        //set the alarm for particular time
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,cur_cal.getTimeInMillis(), PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,1,  intentAlarm, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
        Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm Scheduled for Tommrrow", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}
```

**AlarmReciever.java**

```
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AlarmReciever extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub



       String message="Hi I will be there later, See You soon";



        // Show the toast  like in above screen shot
        Log.d("Alarm",message);
        Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm Triggered and SMS Sent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

//        Intent intent2 = new Intent(context, NotificationReceiverActivity.class);
//        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, (int) System.currentTimeMillis(), intent2, 0);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mNotifyBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                context).setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("Alaram Fired")
                .setContentText("Events To be Performed").setSound(alarmSound)
                .setAutoCancel(true)

                .setVibrate(new long[]{1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000});
        notificationManager.notify(0, mNotifyBuilder.build());
    }

}
```

**NotificationRecieverActivity.java**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;

public class NotificationReceiverActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_notification_receiver);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

**BootCompletedReciever.java**

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class BootCompletedReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {



    }
```

**Manifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="voice1.theacetechnologies.com.alarmcheck2" >

    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name=".BootCompletedReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name=".AlarmReciever"
            android:process=":remote" />

        <activity
            android:name=".NotificationReceiverActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_notification_receiver"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

So the application works fine. However if you restart the phone or turnoff-turn on within the 10 minutes (lets say you did this 8 minutes before completing the 10 mins), you will receive the notification as soon as phone is on, before completing the 10 mins.

what have i done wrong here?

Comment: In your BootCompletedReceiver you Toast out the message no matter if the Alarm actually triggered or not.

Comment: @Fildor: That's not the issue, the notification comes before 10 minutes.

Comment: @MikeM.: The `Toast` is not the issue at all,  the notification comes before 10 minutes.

Comment: Ah, me too, I thought you were mistaking the Toast for the actual trigger. I'll reconsider ...

Comment: @MikeM.: oh, OK. Any solution for my question?

Comment: @MikeM.:Thanks. Question is updated now with the Manifest

Comment: @MikeM.: No, nothing else.

Comment: when you boot on your device, can you see the log "Alarm"?

Comment: @MikeM.: The notification comes up without a need to open the app, thats what I also required. Regarding the log, what is "Alarm" log please?